# database design for complex time range

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

I have a reservation of tickets on a site.
I need to save time, after which I must drop the reservation.
I have a simple condition:

```
drop reservation after 30 minutes after reservation
```

and complex:

```
from 00:01 to 18:00 -  drop after 20 hours, from 18:01 to 00:00 - drop after 16 hours.
```

How to design database for this?
Now I have simple `TimeSpan` field in a `C#` class. And, it's enough for simple rule, but not for complex rules.
Thanks.

PS. The DB is MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: surely you just save he drop time in the reservation. The logic and calculation exists outside the database, or, do you want to be able to change the rules with a retrospective effect?

Comment: @Jodrell: these fields will be editable in the CMS.

Comment: you'll have to explain the implication of your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be controlling the time frame with the server and SQL. This should be done in your application. So for each reservation you create a timestamp (stored in the database as column ExpiryTime - or whatever you want). Periodically you check the column ExpiryTime to see if a given reserveation has timed-out or not. if it has perform the operation to remove the reservation...

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could infact just use the expiry time in the where clause when you retrieve reservations. Leaving old reservations in place as a historical record or delete them with some maintenance task or job during lulls in activity. +1 for making my comment an answer.

Comment: @Killercam: I don't want to controlling the time. L just want to set it.

Comment: Ok. Well you just create a column in the `Reservations` table (assuming you have this or something simalar) called `ReservationTime`/`BookingTime` or whatever you want and write each booking and the time it was made to the database using an update statement: `UPDATE Reservations SET ReservationTime = [SomeTime] WHERE BookingIndex = '{0}';` or somesuch query...

Comment: The question in that how can I store complex rule from example.

Comment: Just store two fields `BookingTime` and `ExpiryTime` as `DATETIME` fields in the SQL Database/DataTable. Then check their values according to your logic. An example of the logic is in my answer and @Jodrell's comment above.